# making bootstrap tabs responsive

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4

Im using [bootstrap-vueJS tabs](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/tabs) and currently I'm not satisfied with it because it is not responsive.

[image]

Is there a way where i can make it responsive? or any alternative for it.

Comment: There's no way with Bootstrap out-of-the box, but you can do something like https://www.codeply.com/go/Loo3CqsA7T

Comment: is there a way without using jquery?